# Modify same values of a variable in R

Tags: r

My data frame is like this:

```
Name   No
X      1
X      3
YYY    1
YYY    6
X      8
X      2
X      1
```

I want to change the name of the last 3 X to something not X (X1 for example). Basically same values but not continuous must be modified. There are many cases like this in my Name variable. Is there any way to do it in R? It is quite like `not-sorted` in SAS.

Thank you very much

Comment: Is this based on position or some patterns?

Comment: It is based on position

Comment: In that case the below one should work

Comment: What is wrong with the solutions posted by me?  You said it is based on the position first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rle` suggests itself here for "*same values but not continuous must be modified*"

```
r <- rle(as.character(df$Name))
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:3] 2 2 3
#  values : chr [1:3] "X" "YYY" "X"

r$values <- make.unique(r$values,sep="")
inverse.rle(r)
#[1] "X"   "X"   "YYY" "YYY" "X1"  "X1"  "X1"

df$Name <- inverse.rle(r)
df

#  Name No
#1    X  1
#2    X  3
#3  YYY  1
#4  YYY  6
#5   X1  8
#6   X1  2
#7   X1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with only simple `base R` functions

```
df1$Name <- with(df1, paste0(Name,  cumsum(c(TRUE, Name[-1]!= Name[length(df1)])),
         Name, FUN = function(x) {
              x1 <- match(x, unique(x))-1
              replace(x1, !x1, "")})))
df1
#   Name No
#1    X  1
#2    X  3
#3  YYY  1
#4  YYY  6
#5   X1  8
#6   X1  2
#7   X1  1
```

---

Or using `rle` with `ave`

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df1$Name), {
            v1 <- ave(seq_along(values), values, FUN = seq_along)-1
            values <- paste0(values, replace(v1, !v1, ''))}))
#[1] "X"   "X"   "YYY" "YYY" "X1"  "X1"  "X1"
```

NOTE: The above solutions gives the expected output that the OP mentioned in the post and do not include any `.`

---

Or another option is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, gr := rleid(Name)]
unique(df1[, c("Name", "gr"), with = FALSE])[, 
   Name := make.unique(Name)][df1, on = 'gr'][, 2:3 := NULL][]
#   Name No
#1:    X  1
#2:    X  3
#3:  YYY  1
#4:  YYY  6
#5:  X.1  8
#6:  X.1  2
#7:  X.1  1
```